# Entities created correctly from Json with @JoinColumn on the opposite side

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, joincolumn

I thought I understood the JPA's *@JoinColumns* annotation and *mappedBy* parameter, but then I needed to create new entities from this Json of a **Question**. It has a set of answer choices which need to be mapped to new entities as well. I decided that the Question entity is gonna be the owning side, therefore I omitted the mappedBy parameter. When I used the @JoinColumns annotation on the **AnswerChoice** side, all the entities were created from the Json objects, but the AnswerChoices' FKs to the Question entity were not set.

Putting the @JoinColumns in the Question entity solved the problem, but my question is: is this the correct way? Will I be facing any side effects? Should I instead have run a for-loop on the set of AnswerChoices and set the FK?

Question Json

```
{
    "text": "Do you know JPA?",
    "answerChoices": [{
        "text": "yes",
    }, {
        "text": "no",
    }, ]
}
```

Controller with a JpaRepository:

```
@PostMapping("/questions/create")
@ResponseBody
public String create(@RequestBody Question json) {
    questionRepo.save(json);
}
```

Question entity:

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="question_id")
    private Set<AnswerChoice> answerChoices;
}
```

AnswerChoice entity:

```
@Entity
public class AnswerChoice {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Question question;
}
```

For the sake of brevity I omitted the auto-generated Id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the mapping is not correct. It actually creates two separate associations that happen to share the join column.

Either remove `question` from `Answer`, making the association unidirectional (ask yourself if you really need that side of the association) or go back to the original solution and use [`@JsonBackReference/@JsonManagedReference`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) (so that the field gets automatically populated during deserialization).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is it bad for two associations to share the same column if it tracks changes from both sides and produces the correct SQL? Additionally, could you elaborate on what technically is an association in JPA - some data structure in memory?

Comment: It is bad to have both sides pretend to be the owner side of an association because such a config behaves unpredictably (e.g. if you set `Answer.question` to `null` but keep the `Answer` in `Question.answerChoices`, the final outcome is anybody's guess)

Comment: Association simply means 'one entity referencing another' (in the OOP sense rather than some JPA-specific meaning) and there are certain ways to tell JPA how to handle them. When there's a logical link between two associations, you can tell JPA that those two are part of one and the same bidirectional association using `mappedBy` on one of the sides (which is telling JPA: 'the DB mapping for this association is defined in the other entity') . Your mapping simply doesn't allow JPA recognize that yours is a bidirectional association. It may work at times and fail spectacularly at others

Answer (score 3):

As told by @crizzis, your mapping is not correct, usually, the child is at the owning side of the relationship(when 1-to-many is big with a single domain), but in your case, `Question` is the owning side of the relationship since you have `@JoinColumn`. So you can completely get rid of `Question` reference from `AnswerChoice`. When you create Question with Answer choices hibernate will

- create questions
- create answers
- updates answers foreign key to questions

If you remove this line `@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_question_id"))` from Question entity, hibernate will create extra table to manage this relationship called `question_answer_choices` hence to get rid off extra table we manually specify which column will be reference in `AnswerChoice` to map to foreign key.

Entity `Question.java`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_question_id"))
    private Set<AnswerChoice> answerChoices = new HashSet<>();

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void addAnswerChoice(AnswerChoice answerChoice) {
        if (answerChoice != null) {
            this.answerChoices.add(answerChoice);
        }
    }

    public Set<AnswerChoice> getAnswerChoices() {
        return answerChoices;
    }
}
```

Entity `AnswerChoice.java`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer_choice")
public class AnswerChoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    private String content;

    public AnswerChoice() {
    }

    public AnswerChoice(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Test code below

```java
    @Test
    public void testQuestionAndAnswersTest() {
        Question question = new Question();
        question.setDescription("How is the weather today?");

        question.addAnswerChoice(new AnswerChoice("Sunny"));
        question.addAnswerChoice(new AnswerChoice("Cloudy"));
        question.addAnswerChoice(new AnswerChoice("Rainy"));
        question.addAnswerChoice(new AnswerChoice("Windy"));
        question.addAnswerChoice(new AnswerChoice("Snowy"));

        //child entities persisted together
        entityManager.persist(question);


        Question searchedQuestion = entityManager.find(Question.class, question.getId());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(searchedQuestion);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(searchedQuestion.getId());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(searchedQuestion.getAnswerChoices());
        Assertions.assertEquals(5, searchedQuestion.getAnswerChoices().size());
        Set<AnswerChoice> answerChoices = searchedQuestion.getAnswerChoices();
        for (AnswerChoice answerChoice : answerChoices) {
            Assertions.assertNotNull(answerChoice.getId());
        }
    }
```

Table statements generated are as below:

questions.sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

answer_choice.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `answer_choice` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_question_id` (`question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```